# Leave Event Handler works only once

Tags: c#

Upon leaving a textbox, a value gets calculated in another textbox using the 'Leave' Event Handler. It works fine as long as I only do it once. When I type in a different number and leave the textbox it doesn't calculate. Below is the code. The void Ratio_Photon_1() is the calculation of the two textbox values. How can I get it to calculate every time I leave the textbox.

```
 void Ratio_Photon_1()
    {
        double Ratio;

        double RDG1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtRDGPhoton_Energy1.Text);
        double RDG2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtRDGPhoton_Energy1_Energy.Text);

        Ratio = RDG2 / RDG1;

        txtCF_Photons_Energy1_Energy.Text = Convert.ToString(Ratio);
    }

 private void txtRDGPhoton_Energy1_Energy_Leave_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ratio_Photon_1();

        if (Convert.ToDouble(txtCF_Photons_Energy1_Energy.Text) > 1)
        {                
            MessageBox.Show("RATIO IS GREATER THAN 1. MAKE SURE TO CHECK SETUP.", "SETUP CHECK", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "_it doesn't calculate_" Why? Could you debug and tell? And Please use proper variable names, looks like it is confusing for everyone.

Comment: The program simply doesn't do anything. The original number remains in the textbox.

Comment: Step through your code and tell the values.. See what is happening on every `Leave`. "_Questions seeking **debugging help** ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._"

Comment: One Leave event handler is not enough, clearly you also need one for txtRDGPhoton_Energy1 since it affects the calculation.  Hardly the only thing you need to do, type "asdf" in the textbox and watch it bomb.  Once you fixed that, the TextChanged event starts to get interesting.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. Yes I've taken care of the alpha and decimal problem of the textbox in another part of the code. It won't allow them to be typed in using the KeyPressEventArgs. It can only insert numbers and decimals. I will work on what you suggested.